# xcode view size smaller than iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib, autolayout

That never happened before iOS 6.
Now, I create an "auto layout", and I realized that the size was different in xcode, because the image was large but was correct in photoshop. When creating the app in the simulator, I have this:
[image]

I kept finding weird. So checked the size of the iPhone 5 and moved, as I always did, then looked like this:
[image]

When creating the app in the simulator, looked like this:
[image]

I wonder what happened with Xcode? Someone went through this already?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are working with an XIB that was identified as for iPad. In the Attribute Inspector, what options are you given under size? An iPad XIB has these options in Attribute Inspector - Size:

[image]

If that is what you see, you may have to create a new XIB, and be sure to choose Device Family - iPhone.

Comment: Was selected iPhone 5 (Retina 4 Full Screen) and yet was wrong size, see picture 1. Then I moved and changed FreeForm to the actual size of the iPhone 5, and it happened there.

Comment: I select iPhone only when created the project